# Return variable from Python sent from Photoshop

Tags: python, photoshop-script

I can pass a variable (such as the document name) from Photoshop to a Python script (albeit via a batch file)

**Photoshop script hello_world.jsx**

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument; 
var batPath = "C:\\temp\\hello_world.bat"; 
$.setenv("DOC_NAME", docName);
File(batPath).execute();
```

**hello_world.bat**

```
@echo off
python D:\\LearnPython\\hello_world_photoshop.py %DOC_NAME%
pause 100
```

**hello_world_photoshop.py**

```
import sys
args = sys.argv[1:]
docName = " ".join(args)
results = "Photoshop document: " + docName
print (results)
# return results
```

How do I pass a variable back to Photoshop - such as results?

Yes, I realise that this example of getting the document name and running it to Python and back again is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the result of the hello_world_photoshop.py into a file and read it in the photoshop script.

I don't really know if the `File(batPath).execute();` waits for the end of the execution or not. If it does, then you can read the resulting file after this line. If it does not wait, then you could put the execution of javascript to an infinite loop of pauses and checks for a result file updates.

Comment: That worked! I had to put a alert message in a delay. but it worked! Also have to delete the text file before reading as well :)